# apache: bypass authentication for a specific ip

Tags: apache-2.2

In Apache I have set basic authentication for /protected location. Now i need to bypass authetication for a specific ip address but keep auth for others intact.  Can anyone guide me on this one. Here is my current snippet of auth protected location.

```
<Location "/protected">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

  AuthName "Protected folder"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthUserFile /etc/htpasswd
  require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 4):

You use use `Satisfy Any`:

```
Order deny,allow
allow from 1.2.3.4
deny from all
Satisfy Any
AuthType Basic
AuthName "private area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought of doing this. Huge time saver for me.